# XSLT manipulate text scattered across various nodes

Tags: xslt

Input file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- lower UPPER case -->
<document>
  <rubbish> rubbish </rubbish>
  <span class='lower'>
    lower
    <span class='upper'> upper </span>
    case
  </span>
</document>
```

Wanted output:

```
lower UPPER case
```

I know how to get the text included in the outer `span` with `value-of`, but this also
includes the string `"upper"` unchanged which is not what I want.  I do not know how
to manipulate the text in the inner `span` and insert it in the middle of
the other text.

Failed attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//span[@class = 'lower']">
      <xsl:if test="span/@class = 'upper'">
        <xsl:text>do something</xsl:text> <!--TO DO -->
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a recursive approach here, for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="text()[parent::span]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="../@class='upper'">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To understand how this works, read up on built-in template rules: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule

Answer (score 2):

The following approach does away with the `<choose>` and completely pushes the problem down to the match expression:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()[parent::span[@class = 'upper']]">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[parent::span[@class = 'lower']]">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```